# How to create an automatic function in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, function, laravel-blade

As described in the title I want to create an automatic function with php Laravel that launches after the end of each month.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/scheduling

Answer (score 0):

which platform are you hosting your application?

If it is a shared hosting platform then you can do that using cron Jobs, You simply set it to run every month and you are good to go.